# How to recover a Twitter account from an old colleague?

Tags: twitter, account-management, account-recovery

In 2013 I had a Volunteer created a Twitter account for my soccer club and now he no longer works for the club.  I have tried to reach out but no answer.  How can I now get access to my Twitter account?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to continue reaching out to the account owner. It's very rare that Twitter would let you take over an account without explicit permission from the account owner.

Can read more about your options here:

https://follows.com/blog/2017/07/claim-twitter-already-taken